# how to revert changes only for one file with git-svn?

Tags: git-svn

I've corrupted one file and I'd like to revert it back. My project is using git-svn.
So how can I revert this one particular file? Or even better if I could view whole change set of this file.

Detailed steps would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
git revert SHA1_OF_FAULTY_COMMIT
```

add back the changes but don't commit

```
git cherry-pick -n SHA1_OF_FAULTY_COMMIT
```

Modify what needs to be modified, e.g.

```
git reset HEAD file_that_should_not_have_been_modified
```

Commit

```
git commit -m "to_be_merged"
```

Squash the two commits, put a meaningful comment.

```
git rebase -i HEAD~2
```

Review your changes, it should only contains the modification on the single file you:

```
git show
```

You can now push that to svn

```
git svn dcommit
```